# How does posterior predictive mean depend on parameters of the likelihood and prior distribution?

Tags: distributions, predictive-models, compound-distributions

I have come across a problem in my research which deals with the mean of the posterior predictive distribution, i.e.

$$p(x'|x)=\int d\theta p(x'|\theta)p(\theta|x)$$

where $x$ is an observed sample and $\theta$ are the model parameters (we can assume they parameterize the mean, and any other model parameters are fixed).

This can be expressed in terms of the prior $p(\theta)$and parameterized distribution $p(x|\theta)$ as
$$p(x'|x)=\frac{1}{p(x)}\int d\theta p(x'|\theta)p(x|\theta)p(\theta)$$

where $p(x)=\int d\theta p(x|\theta)p(\theta)$.

My question is:

**How does the mean of the the posterior-predictive distribution $ p(x'|x)$ depend on the parameters of the likelihood $p(x|\mu=\theta, \sigma^2, ...)$ and and prior $p(\theta|\mu=\mu_{\theta}, \sigma^2=\sigma^2_{\theta}, ...)$?**

I am particularly interested in the *sign* of the quantity $\Delta \equiv \mathbb{E}_{x'\sim p(x'|x)}[x']-x$, i.e. when the expected value, after observing a point $x$, is (greater than, less than, or equal to) the observed point itself. I don't expect a closed-form expression for the mean in terms of model parameters, I'm more interested in when we get a systematic over- or under-prediction ($\Delta>0$, $<0$, respectively).

The toy example that inspired this question is as follows:

> Consider
> \begin{align}
> p(\theta)&=\mathcal{N}(\theta|\mu_{\theta}=0, \sigma_{\theta}^2)
> \\ 
> p(x'|\theta)&=\mathcal{N}(x'|\mu=\theta, \sigma^2)
> \\ 
> \Rightarrow p(\theta|x)&=\mathcal{N}(\theta|\mu=x\left(\frac{\sigma_\theta^2}{\sigma^2+\sigma_{\theta}^2}\right), \tilde{\sigma}^2)
> \end{align}
> Then $$p(x'|x)=\mathcal{N}\left(x'|\mu=x\left(\frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2+\sigma_{\theta}^2}\right), ...\right).$$
> In particular, the posterior predictive mean is given by $\mathbb{E}_{x'\sim p(x'|x)}[x'] = x\left(\frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2+\sigma_{\theta}^2}\right)$. Namely, it is always less than  $x$ (in magnitude), so $\vert\mathbb{E}_{x'\sim p(x'|x)}[x']\vert-\vert x\vert<0$, that is, the mean predicted $x'$ will always be lower than the observed $x$.

My question ultimately stems from this result: is the fact that $\Delta = \vert\mathbb{E}_{x'\sim p(x'|x)}[x']\vert-\vert x\vert<0$ a general result, and if not, what does it depend on? It's possible this question has no solution, and I would be equally happy to know if this were the case.

Comment: Your question is bit chaotic. The title seems to be inconsistent with the rest of the question: are you asking about relation of posterior predictive mean with empirical mean of the data, or with means of the parameters, or what exactly?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I will try to clarify in the main post.

Comment: The answer to the question in the title is basically : almost never.  There will be always some contribution from the prior, unless the observed data is by coincidence exactly equal to the prior mean (or is measured with infinite precision)

Comment: @Tim I've updated the question, hopefully the example makes it more clear where I'm coming from. I've also changed the title, although I don't know if that helped at all.

Comment: @J.Delaney Sorry for moving the goalposts: I changed the title a bit, and added an example to make clear that I don't necessarily care when they are exactly equal, but I'm curious as to whether the choice of distributions in the problem influence whether the post. pred. mean is greater than or less than the observed sample.

Comment: Your example only holds because the prior mean is lower than the posterior mean. It would be the opposite in the opposite setting.

Comment: @holy_schmitt you've gone almost all the way to answering the question yourself. Just generalize your toy example to have an arbitrary (non zero) mean, and see how it changes your result

Comment: I understand the result for the Gaussian case, but I'm wondering whether any of the results would hold in the case of other distribution families. For example, does the over/underprediction only depend on the ordering of the means in the prior and posterior? Or could skewness/asymmetry play a role?

Comment: @holy_schmitt There are no simple rules. In most cases you would expect the posterior mean to increase if the data is larger than the prior mean, but it's probably not too difficult to find counter-examples with some esoteric distribution. Not to mention that some distributions don't have a defined mean at all.